# Internet Explorer save file instead open php page

Tags: apache-2.2, php, internet-explorer

In my localhost ( http://hotel.local/ ) everything works ok (Max OSX). Now I installed a Virtual Machine for testing my application on IE8.

The fact is that from this virtual machine if I tried to open this application it keeps asking to save a php file instead of opening. If I tried from Chrome for example, it works correctly.

Any help or clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a coding issue, not a server or browser issue. You need to ensure you're sending the correct headers. Some browsers are more accommodating of bad code than others.

Comment: It is possible, in fact, the site uses jQuery Mobile so maybe that the problem.

Comment: jQuery, Mobile or otherwise, isn't a factor. It just comes down to sending the correct headers, which needs to be coded in.

Comment: it was headers problem. Thx!!

Answer (score 1):

Check your `httpd.conf`. PHP is probably not being parsed. Make sure you have the type set:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php php
```

And you use the correct Modules & Handlers:

```
LoadModule php5_module        modules/libphp5.so
AddHandler php5-script        php
```

Comment: I´ve got this configurations. In chrome works perfect, on IE8 it shows "Save file" dialog.